# Is there a word for "a professor who has once taught you in the past"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word or phrase that means "a professor who has once taught me in the past"? All I can think of is "professor from the past." Is there a more formal and proper word for this?

Comment: Also *one of my **old** professors*, *one of my **past** professors*  *one of my **previous** professors*

Comment: @Jim - Perhaps it's obvious, but I'll say it anyway: "old" would be acceptable in conversation, but your other two options are much better in more formal contexts, such as a resumé or job application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply say your *former professor*. There is no specific word or expression.